# Placing jar files in the shared folder of tomcat

Tags: tomcat

I have a couple of projects that are using quiet a lot of jar files, I wanna try to place all those jar files in the tomcat/shared folder. I have a problem thought both these projects are using the same jar files but different version. I wanted to know will this cause any problem say if I have both these jar files in the shared folder will this cause confusions while executing the projects. Hope am clear.

I have a_01.jar and a_02.jar different version jar used in 2 separate projects if I keep both the jars together will it cause any issues while running the projects.

Thanks
Anil

Answer (score 0):

Most likely i WILL cause problems because most classloaders usually load only the first version of a class. Maybe it would be best if you put the jars that do not have multiple versions inside the shared folder and the rest in each project that uses that specific version.